# Using Arcpy to manage creating/deleting/updating features

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, editing, feature-class

Let's say we have a "Land" feature class that has several attribute tables attached to it (Owner, documents, etc), pretty much all of the relationships are Many to Many (With relationship class)

Whenever a user creates a new Land Polygon, he manually types in the primary key (I've found no way of automating this), and sometimes one must cut a Land Polygon into 2 (or more), and when that happens, both Polygons end up with the same primary key.

The primary key ideally should always be unique, but then it would break the relationships when the Polygon is cut.

Our users are not very tech savvy, so my idea was to create a simple GUI form using python and arcpy to populate the related tables, but how can I ideally manage the workflow of creating/cutting the Polygons in this scenario?

Comment: Have you investigated using relationship classes?  Their purpose is to manage many to many relationships.

Comment: @PolyGeo those are currently used

Comment: In that case, since you are looking for code, can you present a code snippet that represents your best efforts to try and do this so far, please?